# how to Disable TouchEvent of BackGroundLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, touch-event

Disable `TouchEvent` and `Click` of **BackGroundLayout**.

in my app i have a problem with touchevent. here i have two image to describe.

I create one layout for tutorial purpose only, so that user can understan it batter.
Layout [[image1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neAnV.jpg)with transparent theme and one Button [Got It].

As this tutorial says (Touch any where to draw), user follow this tutorial and touch anywhere it draw line but it also draw that line
on background layout too see [[image2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToIqB.jpg).it draw line on touchevent

I can not understad why it allow to touch one view which is actually in background.

In short when user is following this tutorial it do not allow to touch and draw line on main layout.

and i don't ant to disable touchevent of background view.

I am also checking for disable all child layout of my layout but i still get click and touch event of background layout.
I have same problem with this activity too [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kn3k.jpg)

i put this code in side top layout's touch event

```
    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
  @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
            return false;
        }
```

this code of background layout.

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);

    for (int i = 0; i <  getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child =  getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```